# Windows authentication using phantomjs

Tags: c#, phantomjs, windows-authentication

I'm looking into phantomjs as a possible solution for UI automation in my latest project, but I can't seem to get windows authentication to work properly. I've tried setting the `page.settings.userName` and `page.settings.password`, but the snippet below always gets a **401** and the underlying stack makes no effort to resolve it. My search-fu has failed me, so I come to the community to ask for help.

```cs
var page = require('webpage').create();

page.onResourceReceived = function(response) {
    phantom.exit(response.status);
};

page.open('http://bing.com');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For me this case works perfect.
[mike-rogers solution](http://mike-rogers.github.io/2014/03/09/ntlm-and-proxying-why-not)

```cs
var _driverOptions = new PhantomJSOptions();
var _driverService = PhantomJSDriverService.CreateDefaultService();
_driverOptions.AddAdditionalCapability("phantomjs.page.settings.userAgent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/41.0.2228.0 Safari/537.36");
_driver = new PhantomJSDriver(_driverService, _driverOptions);


using (Impersonation.LogonUser(domain, login, pass, LogonType.Interactive))
{
    using (var proxy = new NtlmProxy(new Uri("http://yoursite.com/"), options))
    {
        _driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(url);
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

There is an open [PhantomJS Issue](https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/issues/11037) with ongoing discussion. It appears that PhantomJS does not support (automatic/integrated) NTLM Authentication, meaning that it will not work against a server that requires Integrated Windows Authentication.

Comment: Any updates  on this issue? does phantomjs support windows auth now?

Comment: It looks like Phantom JS 2.0 can be made to support NTLM/Kerberos authentication. Although it does not look like it does this out of the box. See - https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/issues/13262

Answer (score 0):

You can add your domain credentials to the URL:

```cs
var driver = new PhantomJSDriver();
driver.Manage().Window.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(1024, 1024);
driver.Url = "http://myusername:mypassword@localhost/myapp";
```

I think this might be a version 2 thing, I'm not sure. AFAIK no support for passing through credentials of the current user, which is a shame.